# Remix.js can't redirect from action if using Form component

Tags: typescript, forms, redirect, action, remix.run

I have been looking through Remix docs, but I can't find the answer to this. It seams that you can't redirect from action if you are using Form component from remix.
Here is a stackblitz, take a look:

[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-tozb7g?file=app/routes/first/form.tsx)

Here I have two child route with forms: first/form route contains Form component, and first/another-form route contains simple HTML form tag. When we you hit a submit button in both forms, you should be redirected to parent route, redirect doesn't work from route with Form component.

What is wrong? What do I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be an issue with StackBlitz. I see that Remix is calling the action and returns a 204 response (which is for client-redirect). However, the actual fetch call in the browser is not returning... stays in (pending) until it times out. Are you seeing this same problem on your local app?

[image]
[image]

Here's the same example on Codesandbox and it works just fine as expected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/remix-form-redirect-62pgtl

Comment: Hi Kiliman, thank you for your response. No I haven't tried this on my local machine, I am just playing around with Remix.run on StackBlitz. Hm it looks like a StackBlitz thing, but later I will try this on my local machine and get back with result....

Comment: Everything works OK on local machine. It is probably StackBlitz issuem so I will switch to codesandbox for remix. Thank you